# Report files that would be deleted before actioning the delete - bash

Tags: bash

I'm very very new at bash scripts and I'm currently trying to write a script that deletes all the files on a SMTP server within specified directories that are older than 30 days, which I have working fine. The issue I am now facing is that I have been asked to add a report functionality to it in a sense of - if in update mode - run delete else - report log of files to be deleted - that kind of deal and also, for it to only delete certain types of files such as pdf, JSON and txt etc. Is this possible? The code I have so far is:

```
#!/bin/sh
#Repeart search of specified directory/directories
rep_fileSearch=("/home/user/FilesToGo")
echo "FileDelete - $(date)."
for element in "${rep_fileSearch[@]}"
    do
        (cd "/home/user/FilesToGo/" && find . -maxdepth 100 -type f -mtime +30 );
        #display the directory
        echo "$element";
        nb_fileSearch=$(find "$element" -type f -mtime +30 | wc -l)
        if [[ $nb_fileSearch != 0 ]] 
        then
                find "$element" -type f -mtime +30 -delete -print > "deletedFilesLog"
                echo "Successfully deleted all files older than 30 days!"
        else
                echo "No files older than 30 days, Nothing to delete!"
        fi
done
```

Comment: `#!/bin/sh` executes a POSIX shell that does not support arrays. Use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` instead

Comment: Okay will do thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if in update mode - run delete else - report log of files to be deleted

You could replace the `-delete` in your `find` command with `$1` and, if *update mode* is desired, add `-delete` as the argument of the script; the *log of files* is already in `deletedFilesLog`.

> only delete certain types of files such as pdf, JSON and txt

You can insert the test `-regex '.*\.\(pdf\|JSON\|txt\)'` in the `find` command.